# Can't upload files, php and angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Im trying to upload files using angularJs and PHP.

Im using angular-file-upload, https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload.

The problem seems to be in my PHP-code, because it want move the file to the target directory.

Here is my angular:

$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //Vi har valt en eller flea filer
    //$files är en array innehållande de valda filerna att ladda upp. Dess namn, storlek och typ

```
for(var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++)
{
    var file = $files[i];
    $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'lib/actions.php',
        data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
        file: file

    }).progress(function(evt) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

};

This works great. A POST is made to my PHP-file:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{
    $target_dir = "books/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file))
    {
        echo "YES";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "wrong";
    }
}
```

This always prints "wrong". I can't understand why. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: I think, this is an issue about the path. Let's `var_dump(getcwd())` to see, what is your current directory, and is that has a `books` subdirectory

Comment: @lolka_bolka The output of that is: string(21) "/var/www/cryptlib/lib"

Comment: And where is the books directory? `/var/www/cryptlib/lib/books` or `/var/www/cryptlib/books`?

Comment: @lolka_bolka: Yes, it is inside the lib directory.

Comment: And all the permissions are right? Test with `777`, but don't forget to set back to `775` or `755`.

Comment: @lolka_bolka: I've already tried that. Can it have something to do with $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']? The output of that is like this: /tmp/phpIi0Y4q

Comment: That's ok, that is how temporary files stored. Please tell me, what is the value of `$target_file`

Comment: And try with: `$target_dir = "./books/";`

Comment: The value of $target_file is "books/underscore.js"
The value of $target_file = "./books/"; are "./books/underscore.js"

Comment: It works now. It turned out to be the permissions after all. My bad. Thank you so much for your help :-)

Comment: remember to create "books" folder first

Answer (score 0):

Try using multipart POST type instead of $_FILES, and here is an elegant way to post your files: http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs . This worked for me.

**EDIT**

Better I wrote down here the elegant way, if something happens with the linked site.

You need to create a directive what is attached to your controller, so you can handle the current scope, the directive can looks like this:

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

}]);

Once you've created your directive you can use in your html section like this:

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
```

Okay, now we have my own directive what can handle your file, we need to send to server (localhost in your case). So we make a service for that:

```
.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}
```

}]);

Just like that, you can give this service any url, not just your localhost, and the file, what you want to upload.

But how we do that? Just copy this to your controller:

```
var file = $scope.myFile;
var uploadUrl = 'http://www.example.com/images';
fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
```

This should work. :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.